# Print page with javascript styling

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a page with 60 different inputs. They are all numbers and need to be checked against one of the inputs. If that input is 3 greater than the parent div changes to red. Everything works beautifully except if I try to print the style I give through my javascript function (document.getElementById(classid).style.backgroundColor = "red";) does not display print. How do I get the page to print with the style given by the function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckThisNumber(val, id){
    var x = document.getElementById("a6").value;
    var y = Number(x) +3;
    var classid = "p" + id;
    if((val)>=y) { 
    document.getElementById(classid).style.backgroundColor = "red"; } 
    else { document.getElementById(classid).style.backgroundColor = "white"; }
}
</script>
```

One of the many inputs:

```
<div class="a1" id="pa1">
<strong>A1</strong><br><input type="number" name="a1" id="a1" style="width:95%" onKeyUp="CheckThisNumber(this.value,this.id)">
</div>
```

Comment: Because your browser/printer is set up to not print background colors. Nothing to do with JavaScript/HTML and nothing that JavaScript/CSS/HTML can fix.There is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust but it is not standard.

Comment: Hmm ok. Is there an alternative to background-color that will print? Does border-color work or another option that will give a similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, it is based on the browser's print settings. You can enable it in the browser's settings and it would just print them normally, but by default it is disabled to save ink.

Some browser support a non-standard CSS to force the BG to print

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact
```

info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

And another fall back would be to use box shadows

```
.redBG { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px #FF0000; }
.whiteBG { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px #FFFFFF; }
```

If you are using it on a large textarea, you might need to set the 100px to a much larger value.

Comment: Oooooo... that `webkit-print-color-adjust` is neat. I did not know that.